# Display List values in apex page

Tags: visualforce, apex

I have apex class below  having my_list as a List. I need to display in apex page.

Apex class:

```
global with sharing class poistionController {

 List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> my_list = new List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c>();

 public poistionController(Apexpages.StandardController Account) {

     my_list= [select Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c,Name,Account_OAPI__c,Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c,Id,Territory_OAPI__c,Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c from HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c where Depth_Tracker_OAPI__r.Account_OAPI__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

  }
```

}

Apex page:

```
    <apex:dataList value="{!my_list}" var="c">
      {!c}
</apex:dataList>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

But it is not working . Can someone help me here?

Comment: Do you have a getter for your list ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your List variable and make it public:

```
public List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> my_list { get; set; }

public poistionController(Apexpages.StandardController Account) {
     my_list= [select ...];
}
```

Comment: Hi mast0r! Incorporated the change but it is not showing all the field values

Comment: @saikat You need to set it on the visualforce page by yourself like this: `{!c.Name}, {!c.Account_OAPI__c}` and so on.

Comment: @Mastor! Yes. But that is not showing the column names in table format

Comment: @saikat Use `apex:pageBlockTable` for that. Docs could be found on the internet.